# Regex to match string between two characters in email

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a single string out of an email using regex. The email pattern looks like:

```
name.name.someid@mail.domain.com
```

And I would like to grab the 'someid' section. Meaning I need to match everything before the '@' and after the last period.

I can match everything before the '@' with `(^[^@]+)` however I can't effectively combine it in the regex statement to evaluate only after the last period (I can only get it to match after the first period).

Any pointers would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
/[^.]+(?=@)/
```

Here's a demo: http://regex101.com/r/sW7sR3

Comment: Perfect! Lookahead makes it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\.([^.@]+)@/
```

Without using *lookarounds*, this matches anything that's not an `@` or `.` that comes after a `.` and before `@`.

Comment: IMHO a lookahead would be better in this case.

Comment: Why? IMHO I find them to add complexity.

Comment: Because this requires you to write the `@` twice.

Comment: @Broxzier, classic developer. :)